# Jenkins Ext Email Notification configuration using pre-send script (groovy script)

Tags: svn, groovy, jenkins

I want to know how pre-send script works in Jenkins Extendable email notification. Right now I am using some variables like

Build summary:

> $PROJECT_NAME"
> "Build Number - $BUILD_NUMBER"
> "Build Result - $BUILD_STATUS"
> "Build Time $BUILD_ID"
> "SVN Revision Number $SVN_REVISION"
> "Changes Made By - $CHANGES"
> "$CAUSE"
> "Please see build log as an attachment.

Under default content, but I would like to know how to get more details using a groovy script in rich text format like example bellow.

[image: Jenkins Ext Email notification using pre send script]

Comment: what do you want exactly? more info on build? what kind of?

Comment: I want to know how i can achieve the above result using groovy script in Jenkins.

Comment: Read the documentation. The wiki page has a list of "recipes", a "Template Examples" section, and various attachments.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, as mentioned, [read the documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin).  But, in short:

In the `Content` section of the Email-ext configuration for a job/trigger, enter:

```
${SCRIPT, template="scriptname.template"}
```

...where `scriptname.template` is a Groovy template located in `${JENKINS_HOME}/email-templates`.  You must create the `email-templates` directory yourself.

Example templates and other recipes can be found linked from the [Email-ext documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin).

Something that helps make email templates very convenient to test is the `Email Template Testing` link.  For a given Jenkins job, you'll see it in the left navigation/link area, and in the context drop-down for a job.  Then you simply provide the name of your template (e.g., `scriptname.template`) and the tool uses a selectable build of a given job to render the template.